# Is it valid to swap indices in a double sum in the context of this problem?

Tags: summation, substitution

I'm trying to solve for $\mu_k$ the following equation:

$$\ln\left(\frac{\mu_k}{1-\sum_{j}\mu_j}\right) = \eta_k$$

and the book *Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning* says that to solve for $\mu_k$ first sum both sides over $k$ and then rearrange and back-substitute to give:

$$\mu_k = \frac{e^{\eta_k}}{1 + \sum_{j} e^{\eta_j}}$$

I'm not quite sure what he means, but think he's referring to my work below. If not, what is the correct way to solve this?

$$\begin{align}
\sum_k \ln\left(\frac{\mu_k}{1-\sum_j \mu_j}\right) = & \sum_k \eta_k & \text{(sum both sides over $k$)} \\
\sum_k \frac{\mu_k}{1-\sum_j \mu_j} = & \sum_k e^{\eta_k} & \text{(exponentiate both sides)} \\
\frac{1}{1-\sum_j \mu_j} \sum_k \mu_k = & \sum_k e^{\eta_k} \\
\sum_k \mu_k = & \left(1-\sum_j \mu_j\right) \sum_k e^{\eta_k} \\
\sum_k \mu_k = & \sum_k e^{\eta_k} - \sum_j \mu_j \sum_k e^{\eta_k} \\
\sum_j \mu_j \sum_k e^{\eta_k} + \sum_k \mu_k = & \sum_k e^{\eta_k} \\
\sum_k \mu_k \left( \sum_j e^{\eta_j} + 1\right) = & \sum_k e^{\eta_k} & 
\text{(factor and swap indices... valid?)}\\
\sum_k \mu_k = & \frac{\sum_k e^{\eta_k}}{\sum_j e^{\eta_j} + 1} \\
\mu_k = & \frac{e^{\eta_k}}{1 + \sum_j e^{\eta_j}} & \text{(remove sum over $k$)} \\
\end{align}$$

---

UPDATE: The proper solution (last step above is invalid) to this problem (thanks [Clement C.](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/75808/clement-c)) would be:

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\mu_k}{1-\sum_j \mu_j} = & e^{\eta_k} & \text{(exponentiate both sides)} \\
\mu_k = & \left(1-\sum_j \mu_j\right) e^{\eta_k} & \text{Note: $1-\sum_j \mu_j = \frac{\mu_k}{e^{\eta_k}}$} \\
\sum_k \mu_k = & \left(1-\sum_j \mu_j\right) \sum_k e^{\eta_k} & \text{(sum both sides over $k$)} \\
\sum_k \mu_k = & \sum_k e^{\eta_k} - \sum_j \mu_j \sum_k e^{\eta_k} \\
\sum_j \mu_j \sum_k e^{\eta_k} + \sum_k \mu_k = & \sum_k e^{\eta_k} \\
\sum_k \mu_k \left( \sum_j e^{\eta_j} + 1\right) = & \sum_k e^{\eta_k} & 
\text{(factor and swap indices)}\\
\sum_k \mu_k = & \frac{\sum_k e^{\eta_k}}{\sum_j e^{\eta_j} + 1} \\
1 - \sum_k \mu_k = & 1 - \frac{\sum_k e^{\eta_k}}{\sum_j e^{\eta_j} + 1} & \text{(subtract LHS and RHS from 1)} \\
1 - \sum_k \mu_k = & \frac{1+\sum_j e^{\eta_j}}{1+\sum_j e^{\eta_j}} - \frac{\sum_k e^{\eta_k}}{1 + \sum_j e^{\eta_j}} \\
1 - \sum_k \mu_k = & \frac{1}{1 + \sum_j e^{\eta_j}} \\
\frac{\mu_k}{e^{\eta_k}} = & \frac{1}{1 + \sum_j e^{\eta_j}} & \text{substitute: $1-\sum_j \mu_j = \frac{\mu_k}{e^{\eta_k}}$} \\
\mu_k = & \frac{e^{\eta_k}}{1 + \sum_j e^{\eta_j}}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Interestingly, the most questionable step is one you are not asking about: namely, the last one. How do you justify "remov[ing] [the] sum over $k$"? For instance, if $2+5=3+4$, then $2=3$ and $5=4$?

Comment: @ClementC. Good point. I don't feel that comfortable with that step either. The only thing I can think of is to look at this as we added the summation over $k$ just so we can manipulate the equation. And can view removing it as only being interested in a single index of $k$, since the original function was concerned about $\mu_k$ and $\eta_k$ and not the summation of these variables over $k$.

Comment: What about starting with exponentiation: $$\mu_k = (1-\sum_{j}\mu_j)e^{\eta_k}$$. This is your starting point, keep that somewhere. *Now*, summing over $k$, you get $\sum_k \mu_k =  (1-\sum_{j}\mu_j)\sum_k e^{\eta_k}$; this (solving for $\sum_k \mu_k$) leads to you having an expression for $(1-\sum_{j}\mu_j)$, which you can plug back in your original equation, leading to the result.

Comment: @ClementC. I'm not sure what to do after doing what you describe and ending up with: $$\mu_k = \frac{e^{\eta_k}\sum_k \mu_k}{\sum_k e^{\eta_k}}$$

Comment: From after the summation part, you have $$\sum_k \mu_k = (1-\sum_k \mu_k)\sum_k e^{\eta_k}$$. Reorganizing, you get $$\sum_k \mu_k = \frac{\sum_k e^{\eta_k}}{1+\sum_k e^{\eta_k}}$$, so that $$ (1-\sum_k \mu_k) = \frac{1}{1+\sum_k e^{\eta_k}}$$

Comment: @ClementC. Ah, I updated my question to include the proper solution -- feel free to check my work.

Comment: Skimming it from my phone,  it looks good.

Comment: @Matt: Well done! (+1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,
$$\sum_k \mu_k \left( \sum_j e^{\eta_j} + 1\right) =  \sum_k e^{\eta_k}  \quad \Longleftrightarrow \quad
\sum_k \mu_k =  \frac{\sum_k e^{\eta_k}}{\sum_j e^{\eta_j} + 1}, $$
since $\sum_j e^{\eta_j} + 1$ *does not* depend on $k$.

You are actuall using some rule like 
$$s=\sum_k ca_k \quad \Longleftrightarrow \quad \frac{s}{c}=\sum_k a_k . $$

And with the same arguments we have
$$\sum_j \mu_j \sum_k e^{\eta_k} + \sum_k \mu_k =  \sum_k e^{\eta_k} \quad \Longleftrightarrow \quad 
\sum_k \mu_k \left( \sum_j e^{\eta_j} + 1\right) = \sum_k e^{\eta_k}$$
because
$$\sum_k \mu_k =1\cdot \sum_j \mu_j$$
and we use the well known rule
$$\sum_j a\mu_j + \sum_j b \mu_j = \sum_j (a+b)\mu_j.$$
Here $a=\sum_k e^{\eta_k}$ and $b=1$.

Comment: Ah okay, I will edit my answer.

Comment: What I was really getting at is if: $$\sum_j \mu_j \sum_k e^{\eta_k} + \sum_k \mu_k \Longleftrightarrow
\sum_k \mu_k \left( \sum_j e^{\eta_j} + 1\right)$$

Comment: @Matt See my edit :)